# How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

Run the following code from a directory that contains a directory named `bar` (containing one or more files) and a directory named `baz` (also containing one or more files).  Make sure there is not a directory named `foo`.

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('bar', 'foo')
shutil.copytree('baz', 'foo')
```

It will fail with:

```
$ python copytree_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copytree_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    shutil.copytree('baz', 'foo')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/shutil.py", line 110, in copytree
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/os.py", line 172, in makedirs
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'foo'
```

I want this to work the same way as if I had typed:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cp bar/* foo/
$ cp baz/* foo/
```

Do I need to use `shutil.copy()` to copy each file in `baz` into `foo`? (After I've already copied the contents of 'bar' into 'foo' with `shutil.copytree()`?)  Or is there an easier/better way?

Comment: FYI: [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#l145) is the original copytree function, just copy and patch it :)

Comment: There is a [Python issue about changing `shutil.copytree()`'s behavior](http://bugs.python.org/issue20849) to allow writing to an existing directory, but there are some behavior details that need to be agreed on.

Comment: Just noting that the enhancement request mentioned above has been implemented for Python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#shutil

Answer (score 260, accepted):

This limitation of the standard `shutil.copytree` seems arbitrary and annoying. Workaround:

```
import os, shutil
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

Note that it's not entirely consistent with the standard `copytree`:

- it doesn't honor `symlinks` and `ignore` parameters for the root directory of the `src` tree;
- it doesn't raise `shutil.Error` for errors at the root level of `src`;
- in case of errors during copying of a subtree, it will raise `shutil.Error` for that subtree instead of trying to copy other subtrees and raising single combined `shutil.Error`.

Comment: Thanks! Agree that this seems totally arbitrary! `shutil.copytree` does an `os.makedirs(dst)` at the start. No part of the code actually would have a problem with a pre-existing dir. This needs to be changed. At least provide an `exist_ok=False` parameter to the call

Comment: this gives me an errno[13] permission denied error, any suggestions?

Comment: @Drewdin - um, did you check permissions for the filesystem path from the exception?

Comment: I did, I actually found that i had a mistake in my code. i had my d in the copytree set to dst. It didn't like it. Thanks for the help! +1

Comment: This is a good answer - however Mital Vora's answer below is worth looking at also. They have called copytree recursively rather than calling shutil.copytree() because the same problem will arise otherwise. Possibly consider merging answers or updating to Mital Vora's.

Comment: This fails if given a path that includes a directory which is not empty in the destination.
Maybe somebody could solve this with tail recursion but here's a modification to your code that works
`def copyTree( src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            if os.path.isdir(d):
                self.recursiveCopyTree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)`

Comment: Sorry for that, the darn comments section isn't very flexible with this and I even ran into a character limit so I couldn't explain there clearly what's up.

Comment: Meh, super-annoying. It's 4 years later, and shutil.copytree still has this silly restriction. :-(

Comment: @antred ...but `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()`, which *also* resides in the stdlib, has no such restriction and actually behaves as expected. Given that, there's no compelling reason to attempt to unroll your own (*...typically broken*) implementation. [Brendan Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1547004/brendan-abel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039095/2809027) should absolutely be the accepted solution now.

Comment: Note that [`copy2`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) (see [source code](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2))
 and thus [`copytree`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)
 (see [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shutil.py#L273)) fails if copied directory contains special files (e.g. [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)).

Comment: This function just moves the problem from the top level into the subdirectory level. If we are copying `/foo` to `/bar` and `/bar` exists, then that is cool, but if there is a `/foo/subdir/` and a `/bar/subdir/`, then **that** will choke.

Comment: @Kaz absolutely! And the fix seems really really obvious. Can't we just remove `shutil.` so that copytree calls itself recursively in the case that the target is a directory? We do also have to add a first step now in the function, to `mkdir -p` the destination directory so that it works when the target directory *doesn't* exist yet.

Comment: years later and shutil has fixed this! For all python >= 3.8, there's a `dirs_exist_ok` optional parameter

Answer (score 449):

Here's a solution that's part of the standard library:

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree("/a/b/c", "/x/y/z")
```

See this similar question.

[Copy directory contents into a directory with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034151/copy-directory-contents-into-a-directory-with-python)

- Reference - https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree

Comment: This is a good one because it uses the standard library. Symlinks, mode and time can be preserved as well.

Comment: Noticed a small disadvantage. `distutils.errors.DistutilsInternalError: mkpath: 'name' must be a string`, i.e. it does not accept `PosixPath`. Need to `str(PosixPath)`. Wish list for improvement. Other than this matter, I prefer this answer.

Comment: @SunBear, Yeah, I think that's going to be the case with most of the other libraries that take paths as strings.  Part of the downside to choosing not to make the `Path` object inherit from `str` I suppose, like most of the prior implementations of object oriented path objects..

Comment: Btw, I came across a documented deficiency of this function. It's documented [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue10948). Users of this function were advice to be aware of it.

Comment: While "technically public", please note that the developers of distutils [made it clear](https://bugs.python.org/issue10948) (same link as @SunBear's, thx!) that `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()` is considered an implementation detail of distutils and not recommended for public use. The real solution should be for `shutil.copytree()` to be improved/extended to behave more like `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()`, but without its shortcomings. In the meantime, I'll keep using custom helper functions similar to some of those provided in other answers.

Comment: **The distutils `copy_tree` (in Python 3.6.5) gets confused by directory symlinks. If told to preserve symlinks as a workaround for this, then it complains whenever a symlink already exists, even though it overwrites regular existing files.**  Buggy!

Comment: distutils.dir_util.copy_tree is bugged for me. When I use this multilpe times in succession, such as in unit tests, it has a problem creating files. I would use shutil.copy_tree

Comment: **distutils has been deprecated in Python 3.10** and is planned to be removed in 3.12, see [PEP 632](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/) for info.

Comment: it works but if you delete the created subdirectories and then try to `copy_tree` again with the same contents to the same destination you will get `No such file or directory` error unless you create the subdirectories again that you deleted. so it is caching something behind the scenes. But nevertheless `shutils.copy_tree` has been fixed since python 3.8 `shutil.copytree(src=temp_dir, dst=self.directory, dirs_exist_ok=True)` :D

Answer (score 159):

[Python 3.8 introduced the `dirs_exist_ok` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#shutil) to [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at *src* to a directory named *dst* and return the destination directory. *dirs_exist_ok* dictates whether to raise an exception in case *dst* or any missing parent directory already exists.

Therefore, with Python 3.8+ this should work:

```
import shutil

shutil.copytree('bar', 'foo')  # Will fail if `foo` exists
shutil.copytree('baz', 'foo', dirs_exist_ok=True)  # Fine
```

Comment: @Jay, only if the directory already exists. I left `dirs_exist_ok` out of the first call to illustrate the difference (and because the directory doesn't yet exist in OP's example), but of course you can use it if you want.

Comment: this also works with `pathlib.Path` objects as src and dst arguments :) distutils.dir_util's copy_tree on the other hand requires conversion to string.

Comment: This indeed correctly copies the contents of `bar` into `foo`, as OP suggested. Is it possible to copy the whole `bar` dir into `foo` so that you end up with a structure like `bar/foo`?

Comment: @pcko1, assuming you mean `foo/bar/` and not `bar/foo/`, try `shutil.copytree("bar", "foo/bar", dirs_exist_ok=True)`. A `pathlib.Path` object works as well in case you don't want to hard-code the `/` directory separator.

Answer (score 74):

In slight improvement on atzz's answer to the function where the above function always tries to copy the files from source to destination.

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:
                shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

In my above implementation

- Creating the output directory if not already exists
- Doing the copy directory by recursively calling my own method.
- When we come to actually copying the file I check if the file is modified then only
  we should copy.

I am using above function along with scons build. It helped me a lot as every time when I compile I may not need to copy entire set of files.. but only the files which are modified.

Comment: Nice, except that you have symlinks and ignore as arguments, but they are ignored.

Comment: It is worth noting that st_mtime granularity can be as coarse as 2 seconds on FAT filesystems http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html. Using this code in a context where updates happen in rapid succession, you may find overrides don't take place.

Comment: There is a bug in the second-to-last line, should be:  
  
`if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:`

Comment: What's the purpose of the third and fourth parameters of `copytree()`? Those 2 parameters  -- `symlinks, ignore` -- are never used, so they could be ommitted, right?

Comment: pls check `shutil.copytree` documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html for more details on `ignore` parameter.

Comment: Recursive nature of this function is potentially problematic in python which is not made for deep recursive calls. Depends on depth of directories and if it's a performance problem I guess.

Answer (score 41):

A merge one inspired by atzz and Mital Vora:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import shutil
import stat
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks = False, ignore = None):
  if not os.path.exists(dst):
    os.makedirs(dst)
    shutil.copystat(src, dst)
  lst = os.listdir(src)
  if ignore:
    excl = ignore(src, lst)
    lst = [x for x in lst if x not in excl]
  for item in lst:
    s = os.path.join(src, item)
    d = os.path.join(dst, item)
    if symlinks and os.path.islink(s):
      if os.path.lexists(d):
        os.remove(d)
      os.symlink(os.readlink(s), d)
      try:
        st = os.lstat(s)
        mode = stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode)
        os.lchmod(d, mode)
      except:
        pass # lchmod not available
    elif os.path.isdir(s):
      copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
    else:
      shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

- Same behavior as *shutil.copytree*, with **symlinks** and **ignore** parameters
- Create directory destination structure if non existant
- Will not fail if **dst** already exists

Comment: This is much much faster than original solution when the directory nesting is deep. Thanks

Comment: Did you define a function also named 'ignore' in code elsewhere?

Comment: You can define any function with any name you like before calling copytree function. This function (which could also be a lambda expression) takes two arguments: a directory name and the files in it, it should return an iterable of ignore files.

Comment: `[x for x in lst if x not in excl]` this does not do the same as copytree, which uses glob pattern matching. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: No it does what https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree is doing.
You mix up with the https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns function

Comment: This is great. The ignore was not being utilized correctly in the above answer.

Comment: Recursive nature of this function is potentially problematic in python which is not made for deep recursive calls. Depends on depth of directories and if it's a performance problem I guess.

Answer (score 8):

[docs explicitly state that destination directory should **not** exist](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> The destination directory, named by `dst`, must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent directories.

I think your best bet is to `os.walk` the second and all consequent directories, [`copy2`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) directory and files and do additional `copystat` for directories. After all that's precisely what `copytree` does as explained in the docs. Or you could `copy` and `copystat` each directory/file and `os.listdir` instead of `os.walk`.

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired from the original best answer provided by atzz, I just added replace file / folder logic. So it doesn't actually merge, but deletes the existing file/ folder and copies the new one:

```
import shutil
import os
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.exists(d):
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(d)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                os.unlink(d)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
    #shutil.rmtree(src)
```

Uncomment the rmtree to make it a move function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my pass at the problem.  I modified the source code for copytree to keep the original functionality, but now no error occurs when the directory already exists.  I also changed it so it doesn't overwrite existing files but rather keeps both copies, one with a modified name, since this was important for my application.

```
import shutil
import os


def _copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    """
    This is an improved version of shutil.copytree which allows writing to
    existing folders and does not overwrite existing files but instead appends
    a ~1 to the file name and adds it to the destination path.
    """

    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        i = 1
        while os.path.exists(dstname) and not os.path.isdir(dstname):
            parts = name.split('.')
            file_name = ''
            file_extension = parts[-1]
            # make a new file name inserting ~1 between name and extension
            for j in range(len(parts)-1):
                file_name += parts[j]
                if j < len(parts)-2:
                    file_name += '.'
            suffix = file_name + '~' + str(i) + '.' + file_extension
            dstname = os.path.join(dst, suffix)
            i+=1
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                _copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                shutil.copy2(srcname, dstname)
        except (IOError, os.error) as why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except BaseException as err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
    try:
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    except WindowsError:
        # can't copy file access times on Windows
        pass
    except OSError as why:
        errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise BaseException(errors)
```

Comment: Recursive nature of this function is potentially problematic in python which is not made for deep recursive calls. Depends on depth of directories and if it's a performance problem I guess.

Comment: This is technically true, although in practice I think you are unlikely to encounter such a case. The max recursion depth in python is 1000 by default, so you would need to have a directory structure 1000 folders deep. (Note you can have as many directories as you want in the first level, and for Python's purposes all those calls would count as recursion depth 1). Filepaths are limited to 4k characters so it might actually be rather challenging to make a meaningful file structure 1000 folders deep being limited to three character names or shorter.

Comment: This might not happen much in reality and it is limited to 4k for some system functions, but many common filesystems have no filepath and with that recursive subdirectory limit. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/859945/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-file-path-in-ubuntu and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that expects a `pathlib.Path` as input.

```
# Recusively copies the content of the directory src to the directory dst.
# If dst doesn't exist, it is created, together with all missing parent directories.
# If a file from src already exists in dst, the file in dst is overwritten.
# Files already existing in dst which don't exist in src are preserved.
# Symlinks inside src are copied as symlinks, they are not resolved before copying.
#
def copy_dir(src, dst):
    dst.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = src / item
        d = dst / item
        if s.is_dir():
            copy_dir(s, d)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(str(s), str(d))
```

Note that this function requires Python 3.6, which is the first version of Python where `os.listdir()` supports path-like objects as input. If you need to support earlier versions of Python, you can replace `listdir(src)` by `listdir(str(src))`.

Comment: Since I couldn't edit, I have modified version of @Boris-Dalstein code and added as an anser

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the same task::

```
import os, glob, shutil

def make_dir(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.mkdir(path)


def copy_dir(source_item, destination_item):
    if os.path.isdir(source_item):
        make_dir(destination_item)
        sub_items = glob.glob(source_item + '/*')
        for sub_item in sub_items:
            copy_dir(sub_item, destination_item + '/' + sub_item.split('/')[-1])
    else:
        shutil.copy(source_item, destination_item)
```

Comment: Recursive nature of this function is potentially problematic in python which is not made for deep recursive calls. Depends on depth of directories and if it's a performance problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version inspired by this thread that more closely mimics `distutils.file_util.copy_file`.

`updateonly` is a bool if True, will only copy files with modified dates newer than existing files in `dst` unless listed in `forceupdate` which will copy regardless.

`ignore` and `forceupdate` expect lists of filenames or folder/filenames *relative to* `src` and accept Unix-style wildcards similar to `glob` or `fnmatch`.

The function returns a list of files copied (or would be copied if `dryrun` if True).

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
import stat
import itertools

def copyToDir(src, dst, updateonly=True, symlinks=True, ignore=None, forceupdate=None, dryrun=False):

    def copySymLink(srclink, destlink):
        if os.path.lexists(destlink):
            os.remove(destlink)
        os.symlink(os.readlink(srclink), destlink)
        try:
            st = os.lstat(srclink)
            mode = stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode)
            os.lchmod(destlink, mode)
        except OSError:
            pass  # lchmod not available
    fc = []
    if not os.path.exists(dst) and not dryrun:
        os.makedirs(dst)
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignorepatterns = [os.path.join(src, *x.split('/')) for x in ignore]
    else:
        ignorepatterns = []
    if forceupdate is not None:
        forceupdatepatterns = [os.path.join(src, *x.split('/')) for x in forceupdate]
    else:
        forceupdatepatterns = []
    srclen = len(src)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        fullsrcfiles = [os.path.join(root, x) for x in files]
        t = root[srclen+1:]
        dstroot = os.path.join(dst, t)
        fulldstfiles = [os.path.join(dstroot, x) for x in files]
        excludefiles = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([fnmatch.filter(fullsrcfiles, pattern) for pattern in ignorepatterns]))
        forceupdatefiles = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([fnmatch.filter(fullsrcfiles, pattern) for pattern in forceupdatepatterns]))
        for directory in dirs:
            fullsrcdir = os.path.join(src, directory)
            fulldstdir = os.path.join(dstroot, directory)
            if os.path.islink(fullsrcdir):
                if symlinks and dryrun is False:
                    copySymLink(fullsrcdir, fulldstdir)
            else:
                if not os.path.exists(directory) and dryrun is False:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.join(dst, dir))
                    shutil.copystat(src, dst)
        for s,d in zip(fullsrcfiles, fulldstfiles):
            if s not in excludefiles:
                if updateonly:
                    go = False
                    if os.path.isfile(d):
                        srcdate = os.stat(s).st_mtime
                        dstdate = os.stat(d).st_mtime
                        if srcdate > dstdate:
                            go = True
                    else:
                        go = True
                    if s in forceupdatefiles:
                        go = True
                    if go is True:
                        fc.append(d)
                        if not dryrun:
                            if os.path.islink(s) and symlinks is True:
                                copySymLink(s, d)
                            else:
                                shutil.copy2(s, d)
                else:
                    fc.append(d)
                    if not dryrun:
                        if os.path.islink(s) and symlinks is True:
                            copySymLink(s, d)
                        else:
                            shutil.copy2(s, d)
    return fc
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution has some issue that `src` may overwrite `dst` without any notification or exception.

I add a `predict_error` method to predict errors before copy.`copytree` mainly base on Cyrille Pontvieux's version.

Using `predict_error` to predict all errors at first is best, unless you like to see exception raised one by another when execute `copytree` until fix all error.

```
def predict_error(src, dst):  
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        src_isdir = os.path.isdir(src)
        dst_isdir = os.path.isdir(dst)
        if src_isdir and dst_isdir:
            pass
        elif src_isdir and not dst_isdir:
            yield {dst:'src is dir but dst is file.'}
        elif not src_isdir and dst_isdir:
            yield {dst:'src is file but dst is dir.'}
        else:
            yield {dst:'already exists a file with same name in dst'}

    if os.path.isdir(src):
        for item in os.listdir(src):
            s = os.path.join(src, item)
            d = os.path.join(dst, item)
            for e in predict_error(s, d):
                yield e


def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, overwrite=False):
    '''
    would overwrite if src and dst are both file
    but would not use folder overwrite file, or viceverse
    '''
    if not overwrite:
        errors = list(predict_error(src, dst))
        if errors:
            raise Exception('copy would overwrite some file, error detail:%s' % errors)

    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    lst = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore:
        excl = ignore(src, lst)
        lst = [x for x in lst if x not in excl]
    for item in lst:
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if symlinks and os.path.islink(s):
            if os.path.lexists(d):
                os.remove(d)
            os.symlink(os.readlink(s), d)
            try:
                st = os.lstat(s)
                mode = stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode)
                os.lchmod(d, mode)
            except:
                pass  # lchmod not available
        elif os.path.isdir(s):
            copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if not overwrite:
                if os.path.exists(d):
                    continue
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

Comment: Recursive nature of this function is potentially problematic in python which is not made for deep recursive calls. Depends on depth of directories and if it's a performance problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import os,shutil

def copydir(src, dst):
  h = os.getcwd()
  src = r"{}".format(src)
  if not os.path.isdir(dst):
     print("\n[!] No Such directory: ["+dst+"] !!!")
     exit(1)

  if not os.path.isdir(src):
     print("\n[!] No Such directory: ["+src+"] !!!")
     exit(1)
  if "\\" in src:
     c = "\\"
     tsrc = src.split("\\")[-1:][0]
  else:
    c = "/"
    tsrc = src.split("/")[-1:][0]

  os.chdir(dst)
  if os.path.isdir(tsrc):
    print("\n[!] The Directory Is already exists !!!")
    exit(1)
  try:
    os.mkdir(tsrc)
  except WindowsError:
    print("\n[!] Error: In[ {} ]\nPlease Check Your Dirctory Path !!!".format(src))
    exit(1)
  os.chdir(h)
  files = []
  for i in os.listdir(src):
    files.append(src+c+i)
  if len(files) > 0:
    for i in files:
        if not os.path.isdir(i):
            shutil.copy2(i, dst+c+tsrc)

  print("\n[*] Done ! :)")

copydir("c:\folder1", "c:\folder2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't edit the "Boris Dalstein" answer above so here is the improved version of this code:

**EDIT on the improvements made:**

- The input args could be `str` path or `pathlib.Path` object. Type hint will help.
- If the source is a directory, it will create that directory as well
- types are defined for local variables so no warning by the IDE

```py
# Recusively copies the content of the directory src to the directory dst.
# If dst doesn't exist, it is created, together with all missing parent directories.
# If a file from src already exists in dst, the file in dst is overwritten.
# Files already existing in dst which don't exist in src are preserved.
# Symlinks inside src are copied as symlinks, they are not resolved before copying.
#

def copy_dir(source: Union[str, pathlib.Path], destination: Union[str, pathlib.Path]):
    destination_path: pathlib.Path

    if isinstance(source, str):
        source_path = pathlib.Path(source)
    elif isinstance(source, pathlib.Path):
        source_path = source

    if isinstance(destination, str):
        destination_path = pathlib.Path(destination)
    elif isinstance(destination, pathlib.Path):
        destination_path = destination

    destination_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    if source_path.is_dir():
        destination_path = destination_path.joinpath(source_path.name)
        destination_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    for item in os.listdir(source_path):
        s: pathlib.Path = source_path / item
        d: pathlib.Path = destination_path / item
        if s.is_dir():
            copy_dir(s, d)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(str(s), str(d))
```

Comment: There are already 18 other answers here. Specifically, _how_ is this better? Why should we use this instead of Boris' answer?

Comment: Recursive nature of this function is potentially problematic in python which is not made for deep recursive calls. Depends on depth of directories and if it's a performance problem I guess.

Answer (score -5):

i would assume fastest and simplest way would be have python call the system commands...

example..

```
import os
cmd = '<command line call>'
os.system(cmd)
```

Tar and gzip up the directory.... unzip and untar the directory in the desired place.

yah?

Comment: if you are running in windows... download 7zip.. and use command line for that.   ... again just suggestions.

Comment: System commands should always be a last resort. It's always better to utilize the standard library whenever possible so that your code is portable.

Comment: Not system independent, requires extra space and CPU time for compression and extracting, definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Using system commands can be an effective strategy if the system commands are good and if it's one call which does a lot of things (no problem of the overhead of the call itself), but why zip it and unzip it if it's not transferred over the network?