# How to move all .log and .txt files to a new folder

Tags: python, shutil

I'm having trouble figuring out how to move all .log and .txt files in a certain folder and it's subdirectories to a new folder. I understand how to move one file with shutil. But, I tried to use a loop, unsuccessfully, to move all. Can someone help me with this? Thanks ....

```
 import os, os.path
 import re




 def print_tgzLogs (arg, dir, files):
   for file in files:
      path = os.path.join (dir, file)
      path = os.path.normcase (path)
      defaultFolder = "Log_Text_Files"
      if not defaultFolder.endswith(':') and not os.path.exists('c:\\Extracted\Log_Text_Files'):
         os.mkdir('C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files')
      if re.search(r".*\.txt$", path) or re.search(r".*\.log$", path):

         os.rename(path, 'C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files')
         print path


 os.path.walk('C:\\Extracted\\storage', print_tgzLogs, 0)
```

Below is the trace back error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SQA_log\scan.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.path.walk('C:\\Extracted\\storage', print_tgzLogs, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 263, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 263, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 263, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 259, in walk
    func(arg, top, names)
  File "C:\SQA_log\scan.py", line 16, in print_tgzLogs
    os.rename(path, 'C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files')
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

Comment: You could easily use path.endswith(".txt") instead of re.search(r".*\.txt$", path).

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy multiple files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python)

Comment: @Zsolt Botkai - the problem is moving all .log and .txt files at the same time.

Comment: Shouldn't `shutil.move('time.log', 'C:\\...')` be `shutil.move(path, 'C:\\...')`?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused as to why you're using `shutil.move` on a hardcoded value (`time.log`) instead of on the variable `path`...

Comment: @Pit - @photoionized I started with path but got an error. So, I tried just one file.

Comment: I just posted an answer, maybe `os.rename` helps you. If not, add the error with the traceback to your question so we can assist you further.

Comment: @Pit - I just added the traceback after trying os.rename ....

Comment: @user And that was really helpful in finding the error, as the traceback says: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists`. See my modified answer on how to solve it!

Comment: @Pit - I attached the recent traceback error. I'm double checking everything ... seems to be right.

Comment: @user Thanks for the traceback, just fixed my code once again. Hopefully it works this time!

Comment: @Pit - thanks ... worked like a charm. I have a better understanding of Python thanks to your help.

Comment: @user I'm happy the script worked for you, and even more happy to get you a better understanding of Python! Be sure that, whenever you encounter any errors, you read and try to understand them. And if you are unsure about how a method works, check the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/), they are brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the traceback, the log-files are already existing. The Python docs to the [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) say:

> On Windows, if *dst* already exists, OSError will be raised *[...]*.

Now you can either:

- delete the files manually or
- delete the files automatically using [`os.remove(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove)

If you want the files to be automatically deleted, the code would look like this (notice that I replaced your regular expression with the python [`endswith`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) as suggested by utdemir):

```
import os, os.path

def print_tgzLogs (arg, dir, files):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join (dir, file)
        path = os.path.normcase (path)
        defaultFolder = "Log_Text_Files"
        if not defaultFolder.endswith(':') and not os.path.exists('c:\\Extracted\Log_Text_Files'):
            os.mkdir('C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files')
        if path.endswith(".txt") or path.endswith(".log"):
            if os.path.exists('C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files\\%s' % file):
                os.remove('C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files\\%s' % file)
            os.rename(path, 'C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files\\%s' % file)
            print path

os.path.walk('C:\\Extracted\\storage', print_tgzLogs, 0)
```

Comment: `os.rename` doesn't accept a directory name. Either use shutil.move or build a destination path that includes the file name.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like are trying to use

`os.rename(path, 'C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files')`

to move the file path into the directory C:\Extracted\Log_Text_Files, but rename doesn't work like this: it's going to try to make a new file named C:\Extracted\Log_Text_Files.  You probably want something more like this:

```
os.rename(path, os.path.join('C:\\Extracted\\Log_Text_Files',os.path.basename(path))
```