# Copy files from multiple directories into one directory using Python

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, copy

What is the easiest way to copy files from multiple directories into just one directory using python? To be more clear, I have a tree that looks like this

```
+Home_Directory
  ++folder1
   -csv1.csv
   -csv2.csv
  ++folder2
   -csv3.csv
   -csv4.csv
```

and I want to put  csv1,csv2,...etc all into some specified directory without the folder hierarchy.

```
+some_folder
   -csv1.csv
   -csv2.csv
   -csv3.csv
   -csv4.csv
```

Some solutions I have looked at:

Using shutil.copytree will not work because it will preserve the file structure which is not what I want.

The code I am playing with is very similar to what is posted in this question:
[copy multiple files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python)
the problem is that I do not know how to do this iteratively. Presumably it would just be another for loop on top of this but I am not familiar enough with the os and shutil libraries to know exactly what I am iterating over. Any help on this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsBHT6-hXGM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I thought of. I am assuming you are only pulling csv files from 1 directory.

```
RootDir1 = r'*your directory*'
TargetFolder = r'*your target folder*'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(RootDir1)), topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.csv'):
                print "Found"
                SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
                shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, TargetFolder) #copies csv to new folder
```

Edit: missing a ' at the end of RootDir1. You can also use this as a starting guide to make it work as desired.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I really didn't have to make any tweaks except for the two directories.

Comment: Would be great if there was a .lower() function there just before .endswith() as sometimes, the extension is .PDF or sort of.

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob
import shutil
#import os
dst_dir = "E:/images"
print ('Named explicitly:')
for name in glob.glob('E:/ms/*/*/*'):    
    if name.endswith(".jpg") or name.endswith(".pdf")  : 
        shutil.copy(name, dst_dir)
        print ('\t', name)
```

Comment: This code is helpful to move multiple file one directory to another directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to move all subfolders from the same to a different directory to wherever you want.

```
import shutil
import os
path=r'* Your Path*'
arr = os.listdir(path)
for i in range(len(arr)):
  source_dir=path+'/'+arr[i]
  target_dir = r'*Target path*'
    
  file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
    
  for file_name in file_names:
      shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
```