# Copy Files from Directory to Folders using Python

Tags: python

I Have a folder with 150 pdf files.
I also have a list of 200 names which correspond to a number of those pdf files.
I.e. with the following format:

```
Mark: 100900, 890210, 1212012

Sam: 210102, 203101,

Matt: 123101, 120123, 123123, 123101
```

etc.

I would like to create subdirectories for all the names, and then make copies of the pdf files from the original folder into each of the subdirectories.

What I have now so far is create the directories, but now trying to figure out how to copy files from a seperate folder if there matches with the main list.

```
import itertools
 import os

 dirs = ["Mark","Sam","Matt","..."]

 for item in dirs:
     os.makedirs(item)
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate question. Answer is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python

Comment: Do all the PDFs have the same naming format?

Comment: What I am trying to figure out is how to copy a file if there is a match, it is not just how to copy a file.

Comment: The pdf files are variable in their names, some have numbers and others have words.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Python 2 or 3? Also. What operating system is this using/is this targeted for? This can affect the answers quite significantly

Comment: Ah i see, I am using a MAC OS and Python 2.7

Comment: please state a clear question or describe the expected outcome, the actual outcome and which part you think fails and how

Comment: The question is clear. I have a folder with files. I have a txt file which shows folder <> file relationships. I would like to copy files from the main directory to folder subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html), it is good for working with files in directories

And the code will look as follows:

```
 import shutil
 import os
 from os.path import exists
 from os import listdir

 nameslist = ["Mark: 100900, 890210, 1212012","Sam: 210102, 203101", "Matt: 123101, 120123, 123123, 123101"]

for item in nameslist: 
parts = item.split(': ')
names = parts[0]
numbers = parts[1].split(", ") #get lists from numbers
if not exists(names):  #create directories
    os.mkdir(names)

for f in listdir(os.getcwd()):  
    if f.endswith(".pdf"):
        if f.replace(".pdf",'') in numbers:
            shutil.copy(f, names)
```

Hope this helps.

If your .pdf files are not in the directory of your python file, replace **os.getcwd()** with path to that directory