# Using python to perform multiple Unix commands

Tags: python-2.7, unix

I am a computational chemistry student and I need to create 100 directories and copy several python programs into each of them before submitting each one to my schools cluster to test the effectiveness of a program I am writing. Rather then typing mkdir test1, mkdir test2,... mkdir test100 and then cp ...... hundreds of times I'm hoping to make a python program to do all that work for me. I have seen several posts that are a bit too advanced for me to figure out how to do what they are saying so i'm hoping someone knows how to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand why would someone down vote his humble question.
Nicholas is just having difficulty grasping this idea of reaching his task.
I can agree that the question isn't formatted well, but if read once you will get what he is trying to say.
So, I would recommend others that instead of down voting and discouraging novices please give them a better modular breakdown of their question.
They don't want our exact answers all the time. They are just looking for some directions!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can start by importing os, sys and path.
2. create a for i loop with range till 100.
3. get current working directory as the folder_path
4. create name = "test"
5. in loop do folder_name=name+str(i) use test_path=path.join(folder_path,folder_name) and then do following:

`if not os.path.exists(test_path):
    os.makedirs(test_path)`

This will make directory if not existing.

Then for copying the files into them, you can use the same loop and after step 5 you can move the files in them.

You can refer this [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python) to copy many files into a given directory from another directory.

I hope this helps for you to get a clearer idea and also gives you work to do :P :D

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good to know that it was helpful :)