# How do I copy all files of one specific type from a folder to another folder in Python

Tags: python, text-files, copy-paste, file-manipulation

Im trying to copy a numerous amount of .txt files from one folder to another using a Python script. I dont want to copy one single file at a time, and im not even sure exactly how many txt files are present in the folder. I am looking to scan the folder and copy all text files from it to another folder. I have already tried doing this using the shutil and os libraries to no avail. Can someone please help?

```
import os
import shutil
def start():
    dest = "C:/Users/Vibhav/Desktop/Txt"
    source = "C:/Users/Vibhav/Desktop/Games"
    for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/Vibhav/Desktop/Games"):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy2(dest,source)
```

This is what I have tried doing, but it doesnt work for me. I keep getting this error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Vibhav/Desktop/Games'
```

It would really help me if someone could help me out

Comment: try running script with administrator privilage

Comment: I have tried, but it doesnt work. Forgot to mention that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python

Comment: have you tried using `shutil.copytree()` ?

Comment: No I havent actually, but its fine. The person who answered provided an effective solution with glob so im okay now. That wouldve been useful to think about though, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main mistake: you're trying to copy the directory, not the file.

Rewriting using `glob.glob` to get pattern filtering + absolute path sounds the best option:

```
def start():
    dest = "C:/Users/Vibhav/Desktop/Txt"
    source = "C:/Users/Vibhav/Desktop/Games"
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(source,"*.txt")):
        shutil.copy2(file,dest)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the glob library and implement it