# Finde all possibilities loop - function try

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, shutil, except

I wrote the code and now I have problem that the code finde only the first value (for example only **img**, we have **img2** too, but it went to another picture) and copy only one, but we have 2 possibilities.

```
for i in df_list:
    img = (filepath + i + ".jpg")
    img2 = (filepath + i + "-1" + ".jpg")
    img3 = (filepath + i + "-2" ".jpg")
    img4 = (filepath + i + "-3" + ".jpg")
    img5 = (filepath + i + "-4" + ".jpg")
    img6 = (filepath + i + " -5" + ".jpg")
    try:
        shutil.copy(img, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)

    except:
        try:
            shutil.copy(img6, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)

        except:
            try:
                shutil.copy(img2, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)

            except:
                  try:
                    shutil.copy(img3, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)

                  except:
                        try:
                          shutil.copy(img4, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)

                        except:
                                try:
                                    shutil.copy(img5, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)

                                except:
                                    with open("C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/J/"+datum+"/"+"Napake.txt", "a") as text_file:
                                      print("Slika za ident {} ne obstaja.\n".format(i), file=text_file)
```

I neeed help, thank you for answers.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: How can I copy more than one possibilities?

Comment: is there any conditions on file copy?

Comment: I have differend names of pictures, for example (picture, picture1, picture2). I  copy only the first picture which is found (this is name picture), but I have picture1 and two too.

Comment: what you mean by "which is found (this is name picture)" where it is found. Edit your question with proper details

Comment: Sorry I forgot the code before. I found the name in excele file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216043/discussion-between-komatiraju032-and-matija).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying the try,except you can loop over the filenumbers and try copy each file. and print an error if there is an exception.

```
save_path = "C:/Users/" + user + "/Desktop/J/" + datum + "/" + "Napake.txt"
for folder in df_list:
    for index in range(6):
        if index == 0:
            img = filepath + folder + ".jpg"
        else:
            img = f"{filepath}{folder}-{index}.jpg"

        try:
            shutil.copy(img6, newpath, follow_symlinks=True)
            with open(save_path, "a") as text_file:
                text_file.write(f"Slika za ident {folder}-{i} ne obstaja.\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print('could not copy file')
            print(e)
```

I would also recommend having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3399299/6372042) to see how to copy all files in a directory.