# How to improve speed of copy files in Python?

Tags: python

I need to copy ~ 100,000 files; copying one file is too slow compared to the Unix terminal cp -r recursive copy of all files in the directory. Is there a way to copy all files instead of copying each file via Shutil? copy() in the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python) Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python/3397772#3397772) specifically.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any evidence, but I really doubt that Python is going to be faster than a simple Unix command. However, if you want to give it a shot, here it is using `shutil.copytree`:

```py
import shutil

source_directory = "/path/to/source"
destination_directory = "/path/to/destination"

shutil.copytree(source_directory, destination_directory)
```

What might be faster though, is using multiprocessing to copy over files. Like this:

```py
import multiprocessing
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

def copy_file(source_file, destination_directory):
    shutil.copy(source_file, destination_directory)

source_directory = Path("/path/to/source")
destination_directory = Path("/path/to/destination")
files = [file for file in source_directory.iterdir() if file.is_file()]

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    # starmap lets us pass multiple arguments to the function
    pool.starmap(copy_file, [(file, destination_directory) for file in files])
```

UPDATE:

I tested the multiprocessing example on 10k empty txt files and these were the results:

```bash
$ time cp /path/to/source/* /path/to/destination/
real    0m0.191s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.158s

$ time python test.py
real    0m0.351s
user    0m0.966s
sys     0m0.615s
```

So I don't think using Python will help you out, but, you can always try!

Answer (score 1):

```
#Code start
import shutil

src_dir = '/path/to/source'
dst_dir = '/path/to/destination'

shutil.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir)

#code end
```

The source directory (src_dir) and the destination directory (dst_dir) will both have all of their files and subdirectories copied across. It should be noted that before executing this code, the target directory shouldn't exist.

```
#code start

import os
import shutil

src_dir = '/path/to/source'
dst_dir = '/path/to/destination'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for file in files:
        src_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, os.path.relpath(src_path, src_dir))
        shutil.copy2(src_path, dst_path)

#code end
```

Comment: Stackoverflow had its own syntax for marking code snippets, which it then formats nicely. You should not invent your own format. See [how do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77576400/edit) your answer to format it properly.