# Copy directory contents into a directory with python

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

I have a directory /a/b/c that has files and subdirectories.
I need to copy the /a/b/c/* in the /x/y/z directory. What python methods can I use?

I tried `shutil.copytree("a/b/c", "/x/y/z")`, but python tries to create /x/y/z and raises an `error "Directory exists"`.

Comment: Are you trying to move or copy the directory over? Your title says move, but your content says copy. Since these are two different things, it matters exactly which one you mean.

Comment: Maybe give an example of before and after, to make it clearer what you want the effect to be, as well?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll update the heading. It's copy, not move.

Comment: Np. Also, like @Xymostech said, we're slightly unclear on the desired output. Do you want: /x/y/z/a/b/c or /x/y/z/c? Your use of `copytree` implies the former, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Could you simply delete any `/x/y/z/` directory first (`shutil.rmtree()`) and then do `copytree()`?

Comment: @EOL: The issue is that I need to keep the existing files/directories in "/x/y/z".

Comment: @prosseek: Do you need to do this at all depths? i.e. if you have `/a/b/c/t/u`, do you need to keep any `/x/y/z/t/v`? i.e. do you only need to create/overwrite, without deleting anything?

Comment: Your problem was my solution.  Thanks for your question.

Comment: This is no longer an issue as of Python 3.8 via the `copytree`'s `dirs_exist_ok=True` flag. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)

Answer (score 231, accepted):

I found this code working which is part of the standard library:

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

# copy subdirectory example
from_directory = "/a/b/c"
to_directory = "/x/y/z"

copy_tree(from_directory, to_directory)
```

Reference:

- Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree
- Python 3:  https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree

Comment: An excellent solution, I suggest adding `update=1` to copy_tree() if that is what you need.

Comment: Just bear in mind that copy_tree will fail if you call it twice for same set of args, and you've wiped the destination in the meantime. This is due to path caching in mkpath, see https://bugs.python.org/issue10948

Comment: What if I want to overwrite all existing files no matter what. Does this function overwrite existing files if update=0?

Comment: funnily enough shutil.copy2 in a loop is much faster than copying the directory as a whole.

Comment: If you repeatedly copy folders into the same destination, DO NOT USE this function. as @yacoob stated, this will fail in an unexpected way. Figuring it out gave me a headache. I am commenting again to increase visibility for others.

Comment: FYI pathlib Path objects break dir_utils, which wants paths as text.

Comment: @yacoob does that mean we should not use copy_tree or this answer? what is the proper and safe way to do this?

Comment: is this a better way? at least it does not do weird stuff https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331781/1601580 `call(['cp', '-a', source, target])`

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12`

Comment: This will get removed in python 3.12

Comment: Ridiculous. I want to copy a directory and you have to import some non-obvious library then find it doesn't work in recent versions of Python.

Comment: What's the 2024 solution here?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use glob2 to recursively collect all paths (using ** subfolders wildcard) and then use shutil.copyfile, saving the paths

glob2 link: https://code.activestate.com/pypm/glob2/

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import call

def cp_dir(source, target):
    call(['cp', '-a', source, target]) # Linux

cp_dir('/a/b/c/', '/x/y/z/')
```

It works for me. Basically, it executes shell command **cp**.

Comment: yes, but this is not pythonic way :)

Comment: @ArtsiomPraneuski I agree, but sometimes may be helpful. :)

Comment: Does not work aside POSIX

Comment: Thanks! This is much faster than other methods!

Comment: @Alldb Is it faster? Have you benchmarked it?

Answer (score -15):

The python libs are obsolete with this function. I've done one that works correctly:

```
import os
import shutil

def copydirectorykut(src, dst):
    os.chdir(dst)
    list=os.listdir(src)
    nom= src+'.txt'
    fitx= open(nom, 'w')

    for item in list:
        fitx.write("%s\n" % item)

    fitx.close()

    f = open(nom,'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if "." in line:
            shutil.copy(src+'/'+line[:-1],dst+'/'+line[:-1])
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(dst+'/'+line[:-1]):
                os.makedirs(dst+'/'+line[:-1])
                copydirectorykut(src+'/'+line[:-1],dst+'/'+line[:-1])
            copydirectorykut(src+'/'+line[:-1],dst+'/'+line[:-1])
    f.close()
    os.remove(nom)
    os.chdir('..')
```