# Copy directory in another directory

Tags: python, directory, copy

I have a directory `D:/INPUT/test1` that I'd like to copy in another directory `D:/OUTPUT`.

I tried many methods but none of them have worked.

For example I tried the method explained at [Copy directory contents into a directory with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034151/copy-directory-contents-into-a-directory-with-python), that is to say :

```
import distutils.core

# copy subdirectory example
fromDirectory = "D:/INPUT/test1"
toDirectory = "D:/OUTPUT"

distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory)
```

The directory `D:/OUTPUT` is well created but there is nothing inside.

Then I tried the `shutil.copytree` method but I get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

```
import shutil, errno

def copyanything(src, dst):
try:
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
except OSError as exc: # python >2.5
    if exc.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
    else: raise
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your code but it did not work. I have not the "INPUT directories" in "D:/OUTPUT"..

Comment: Give more details, because the solution by Robert worked well for me

Comment: I work with Python 2.7 on Windows. I wrote the Robert's code by adding that **src** corresponds to "D:/INPUT/test1" and **dst** corresponds to "D:/OUTPUT". When I execute the code, I have no error message. But the "D:/INPUT/test1" directory has not been copied into "D:/OUTPUT"