# combine 2 directories with it subdirectories

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a problem with combining 2 folder with it subdirectories, i have 2 folder source. i named it : `test-2` and `test-2` and path to these folder is `output/test-2` and `output/test-4`

i combined it with this line:

```
merged_folder_path = 'merged/dir/output'
shutil.copy(result_1_path, merged_folder_path)
shutil.copy(result_2_path, merged_folder_path)
```

but it get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jamu.py", line 769, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "jamu.py", line 757, in main
    shutil.copy(result_1_path, merged_folder_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output/test-2'
```

is something wrong with my code?

Comment: This doesn't look like a Python problem. I suspect you don't have suitable permissions to access the directories you are moving. If you're on a unix-like system, try changing the permissions with `chmod`.

Comment: i use windows by the way,
i have change permissions the directories and subdirectories with cacls
with 

`cacls myfoldername /t /e /g everyone:f`

from [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1638-using-cacls-to-modify-file-folder-permissions-for-users-groups-in-batch-file)
but it's still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy directory contents into a directory with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034151/copy-directory-contents-into-a-directory-with-python)

Comment: yes oin, i found a solution from that link too.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i get the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034151/copy-directory-contents-into-a-directory-with-python).

and it's working to me,
thanks for all the answers. apreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

Check perms before copy/move/delete

```
import os
if os.access(merged_folder_path,os.W_OK):
    shutil.copy(...,...)
```

- os.F_OK: path is exists
- os.R_OK: readability of path.
- os.W_OK: writability of path.
- os.X_OK  path can be executed.