# How can i copy a directory containing a particular file with particular extension in a variable in python

Tags: python-3.x

How can i copy a directory containing a particular file with particular extension in a variable  in python
Note that the file may be present in sub folder too.
Since I am a beginner I would like to have some help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034151/copy-directory-contents-into-a-directory-with-python

Comment: Please elaborate on what you need to do, because as-is your question is very difficult to understand. An example, and the code you have already tried may help us to understand.

Comment: Example : Source directory:  "xx/yy/zz"    and in this source directory let us consider there is a file with particular extension say .zip. If that is the case then copy the source directory to destination directory.      Note: THE SOURCE directory structure keeps on changes. I was trying to use os.walk to detect the .zip extension

Answer (score 1):

Python code for this.

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

fromDirectory = "/user/"
toDirectory = "/windows/"

copy_to_file(fromDirectory, toDirectory)
```

Comment: Thanks again . But I need to detect the particular extension say .zip copy that directory in the todirectory