# How to copy a folder into an existing folder using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, copy-paste, subdirectory

I am new to python, and am currently trying to copy a folder 'foo' (potentially with some files/folders inside) into another existing folder 'bar'. After this, there should be a new path created that should look something like this "...bar/foo/*".

By copying 'foo' into 'bar' I do not wish to have the original contents in 'bar' to be removed, and the only changes in 'bar' is a new subfolder 'foo' being added.

I have tried to search online for the solution, but was not able to find any libraries that provide such a feature. I would highly appreciate it if I could be provided with some information on how to get started, as I am in need of this feature for another item that I am working on.

The current python version I am using is 3.8.9, so I am able to use any new libraries that were introduced from 3.0 onwards. The platform I am working on is windows.

Comment: does this help?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034151/copy-directory-contents-into-a-directory-with-python]

Comment: @Almos I have tried that, but it only copies the contents within the source directory over to my destination directory. I am looking for a way to copy the directory itself (with its contents) into my source directory. E.g. my directory 'foo' contains a text file 'baz.txt'. Using shutil.copytree() will only copy 'baz.txt' into the source directory 'bar'. 'bar' will not contain the directory 'foo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `copytree()` method. Because it copy the actual content, you need to create the folder first with `os.mkdir`

```
import shutil
import os

directory = "foo"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)    
os.mkdir(path)

source_dir = r"C:\foo"
destination_dir = r"C:\bar\foo"
shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination_dir)
```

Some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Another solution is to use directly the command line and launching the copy/paste command from there

You can do it by importing the os `import os` and then with `os.system(my_command)` where `my_command` is the string containing the actual command. In linux you can use `cp -r directory-1 directory-2` (to copy a directory, you need to add the `-r` (or `-R`) flag—which is shorthand for `--recursive`)

```
os.system('cp -r C:\foo C:\bar')
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I have tried to use shutil.copytree, and also included a dirs_exist_ok=True in the method call. But what I get is the contents in 'foo' are copied over to 'bar'. I intend to have the entire folder 'foo' inside 'bar' when copying the folder 'foo' into 'bar'. I am using windows to run my script, so the latter solution won't work for me

Comment: so you can create the folder `\bar\foo` and then copy the content. Coded added

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution that can be used with source paths that change at runtime, you can use `os.path.basename` to peel off the directory name from the source and tack it on the destination:

```
import shutil
import os

full_original_directory_name = "/deeply/nested/directory/name"
target_directory = "/some/other/path"

src = full_original_directory_name
dst = os.path.join(target_directory, os.path.basename(full_original_directory_name))
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```