# merge child directory into parent directory structure python

Tags: python, directory-structure, shutil

I have this directory structure...

```
└── 01048
    └── 2014
        └── IN
```

I want to merge this directory structure...

```
└── 01048
    └── 2014
        └── AR
        └── AB
```

To make this directory structure...

```
└── 01048
    └── 2014
        └── IN
        └── AR
        └── AB
```

I've tried `shutil.move("../scr_path/01048", "../destination_path/01048")` but that results in...

```
└── 01048
    └── 01048
        └── 2014
            └── AR
            └── AB
    └── 2014
        └── IN
```

Comment: Please post the code you wrote that uses `shutil.copy()` so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try-out `shutil.move` , along with `os.listdir()` to move your directories.

Example -

```
import os, os.path
import shutil
for src in os.listdir('../scr_path/01048'):
    s = os.path.join('../scr_path/01048',src)
    d = os.path.join('../destination_path/01048',src)
    for src1 in os.listdir(s):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(s,src1),d)
```

Comment: this is getting me close, but for some reason i end up loosing the 2014 directory?

Comment: What does it look like now?

Comment: `01048
    └── AR
    └── AB
    └── IN`

Comment: Did you start with the correct directories, like in your question?

Comment: my bad, something was off in my path

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong *destination* path:

```
shutil.move("../scr_path/01048", "../destination_path")
```

If the destination directory already exists, you will have an error. In order to merge two directory trees you can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514470/1003123).