# Python: read a text file and copy/paste directories listed in it to a new directory

Tags: python

I am trying to read a .txt file that lists directory names and copy/paste the listed directories into a new directory. I am pretty close to figuring it out but need a function that copies the directory (not only its contents).

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

dst = '/Users/name/Desktop/Core/TEST'
f = open('/Users/name/Desktop/Core/Core_List.txt','r')
for i in f.readlines():  
    print i
    copy_tree(i.strip(), dst)

f.close()
```

---

This is what ended up working:

```
from shutil import copytree
from os.path import join

dst = '/Users/name/Desktop/Core/TEST'
f = open('/Users/name/Desktop/Core/Core_List.txt','r')
for i in f.readlines():
    print i
    copytree(i.strip(), join(dst,i))

f.close()
```

Comment: It is clear, just contains irrelevant information. The problem is that you need a function that copies the directory itself and not only its contents. Everything else isn't related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Comment: take a look at shutil module

Comment: I've tried to follow "How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?" but it's my first time using Python, so I'm having difficulty incorporating open() with def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
from shutil import copytree
from os.path import join

dst = '/Users/name/Desktop/Core/TEST'
with open('/Users/name/Desktop/Core/Core_List.txt') as f:
    for src in f:
       print src
       copytree(src, join(dst, src))
```

Assuming src is relative to the working directory, it's somewhat more complex if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
copy_tree(i.strip(),dst)
```

with line:

```
copy_tree(i.strip(),dst + '/' + i.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

os.chdir('/Users/name/Desktop/Core/')
f = open('./Core_List.txt','r')
for i in f.readlines():  
    print i
    copy_tree(i.strip(), './TEST/')

f.close()
```

*Note : All 'i' vales must be file-names, not paths.*