# How to copy a folder into another folder in python

Tags: python

copy_tree copies the files and folders under src to dst, it's same as `cp -r a/b/* x/y/` in shell

```
$ tree
.
|__a
|  |__b
|     |__ab.txt
|__x
   |__y

>>> from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
>>> copy_tree('a/b','x/y')
['x/y/aa.txt']
>>>
```

How to make it copy the folder `b` as is? like doing `cp -r a/b x/y/`

I need to copy `b` into `x/y`, so it becomes `x/y/b`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `shutil` library.

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('a/b','x/y/b')
# Returns 'x/y/b'
```

See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) for more info.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplication of ["How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use os.system to use shell commands. It comes handy when you don't know pythonic way but you know bash way. I use it this way.

```
import os
os.system("<command that you want to run in shell>")
```

In this case, you need

```
import os
os.system("cp -r a/b x/y/")
```

Comment: System commands aren't very portable and `shutil.copytree()` is easy to use and part of the standard runtime library. :-)