# Python. Copy Files and Folders to existing directory

Tags: python, copytree

How can I copy all contents (including folders) from folder A to the existing folder B with Python?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. On this website, we encourage you to post your efforts and tell what problem you encountered. For this kind of question, please use google first.

Comment: This may be a duplicate: [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the copytree function from the shutil package https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree.

```
from shutil import copytree

src_path = "path/of/your/source/dir"
dest_path = "path/of/your/destination/dir"

copytree(src_path, dest_path, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

The `dirs_exist_ok=True` parameter is useful if the dest_path already exists, and you want to overwrite the existing files.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the OP asked for.  I think they want to copy the Contents Of  `path/of/your/source/dir` rather than copying the directory itself.