# How to copy a folder in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

I can't believe this hasn't been asked before. I've googled with all queries and quotes and found no result. How the heck can I copy a folder inside jupyter notebook? Like, the whole folder, not just the path, or the files one by one, but the whole folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run shell commands from jupyter notebooks using the exclamation mark in front of the command, e.g.

```
!cp -r /path/to/src /path/to/dest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like the usual python script.

Here's a solution I found from another question:

```py
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree("/a/b/c", "/x/y/z")
```

[How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Comment: This raises a FileNotFoundError for me in Jupyter, but not in a regular Python interpreter.

Comment: I need the same, but for students (we use JupyterHub) for which a graphical "widget" would be a better solution... any idea ?