# Copy a non-empty folder in python

Tags: python, list, shutil

## **How to copy a non-empty folder in Python ?**

I am want use like unix command " cp -r "

Ex..

sourceFolder = /tmp/Folder1/file1.txt

destinationFolder = /tmp/Folder2/

after copying sourceFolder is look like " /tmp/Folder2/Folder1/file1.txt "

I am trying for copy

```
shutil.copytree('/tmp/Folder1/file.txt', '/tmp/Folder2/')
```

Comment: This question already answerd: [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)

Comment: voting to close. I agree with the link you found, @szeak

Answer (score -2):

```
import os
# Copy Created Feature folder and file into 


coping = os.system('cp -rf /tmp/'+folder1+' /tmp/'+folder2+'/')
```

Comment: This solution is not platform independent. What about if using Windows?